# Injecting a Spring Data Rest repository into a utility class

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

After searching for a day, trying all configurations (app context) and annotations (autowire, inject, component, etc), I cannot seem to get my pojo class to inject a working repository successfully -- the value is always null.
I am starting to wonder whether injecting into anything but a controller goes contrary to the architecture of spring data rest.

Here is my application context (taken from spring docs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.test.springservice"/>

</beans>
```

My main class that draws this context in:

```
package com.test.springservice;

import ...

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@ImportResource("classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My working repository and model:

```
package com.test.springservice.greek;

import ...

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface GreekLetterRepository extends CrudRepository<GreekLetter, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT l FROM GreekLetter l WHERE l.translit Like :translit% ORDER BY length(l.translit) Desc")
    public List<GreekLetter> findByTranslitStartsWith(@Param("translit") String translit);

}

package com.test.springservice.greek.model;

import ....

@Entity
@Table(name="letters", catalog="greek")
public class GreekLetter extends Letter {
    public GreekLetter() {}
    public GreekLetter(String name, String translit, String present, String types) { super(name,translit,present,types); }
}
```

And finally, my class that I cannot inject the repository into:

```
package com.test.springservice.greek.model;

import ...

public class GreekString extends Letters {

    @Autowired
    public GreekLetterRepository repository; // this is null (class not managed by container)

    public GreekString(String str) {
        super();
        setTranslit(str);
        if (this.getTranslit().equals(this.getPresent())) { setPresent(str); }
    }
    public void setTranslit(String str) { // litterates from str as translit
        List<Letter> lets = new ArrayList<Letter>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String partialWord = str.substring(i);
            String partialWord0 = partialWord.substring(0,1);
            List<GreekLetter> potentialMatches = repository.findByTranslitStartsWith(partialWord0);
            ....
        }
        ....        
    }
    ....
}
```

Does anyone see a basic flaw in the approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `repository` BEFORE Spring has a chance to inject it in through the `@Autowired` annotation.

One fix could be to use constructor based wiring of GreekLetterRepository:

`public GreekString(String str, GreekLetterRepository greekLetterRepository)`

I don't see where you are instantiating this bean but if it is in a java configuration, you can do it this way:

```
@Bean
public GreekString something(GreekLetterRepository greekLetterRepository) {
    return GreekString("something", greekLetterRepository);
}
```

Now it should work cleanly.

However, I would recommend not using the repository immediately within the constructor, a better place to use the dependent beans is after the entire bean is cleanly initialized, you can annotate a method with `@PostConstruct` to be called once the bean is completely initialized, this way:

```
public class GreekString extends Letters {

    @Autowired
    public GreekLetterRepository repository; 

    public GreekString(String str) {
        super();

    }
   .....

    @PostConstruct   
    public void init() {
       setTranslit(str);
       ...
    }
}
```

One more note:

`@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.springservice:)` and xml `jpa:repositories` serve the same purpose, you can go ahead and remove the xml configuration

Comment: Even better as he is using Spring Boot he can remove it completely, the same applies to `@PropertySource` and the `@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)`. Which would only leave `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which can be replaced with `@SpringBootApplication` (if Spring Boot 1.2.0 is the version used).

Comment: Haven't accepted answer because, even after making the changes, I still am getting null on the injected repository.

Comment: If you can share your code in a github repo, I can send you a fix. It is difficult to see where else the issue could be from the snippets.

Comment: You have not defined `GreekString` as a Spring bean anywhere right, that is the issue, Spring can autowire beans only if they are known to it, if you bypass Spring by using `new GreekString()`, then it is not visible to Spring at all and hence cannot be autowired. Just as a demo I have made `GreekString` a Spring bean here and see both `@PostConstruct` and `afterPropertiesSet` getting called - https://github.com/bijukunjummen/clovis/tree/fixgreekstring

Comment: Cloned your GitHub repo, built with maven and started container (with startcontainer.sh) and still do not see either PostConstruct, or afterPropertiesSet being called when I hit http://localhost:8080/greekWords/1   Strange